# Can't Edit Project Processes on Azure DevOps 2022 On Premise

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfs-process-template, work-item-type

I need to add a work item type and add a new state in Azure DevOps 2022. I see some articles about doing stuff like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-wit?view=azure-devops) from the UI.

I seem to be missing some functionality.

Here there should be a Fields tab according to the documentation.
[image]

I also cannot click and open up any of the processes to see or edit their work item types.
I am a member of the Project Collection Administrators group.
Am I missing an extension or a setting or something to be able to edit this from the UI and not from the XML?

Comment: Hi @Jhenr, have you checked my answer below? Is it helpful for you? If you have any question, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, your collection is using the XML process. According to [Add a custom work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-wit?view=azure-devops-2022#:%7E:text=If%20your%20on%2Dpremises%20collection%20is%20configured%20to%20use%20the%20On%2Dpremises%20XML%20process%20model%2C%20you%20can%20only%20use%20that%20process%20model%20to%20customize%20the%20work%20tracking%20experience), if your on-premises collection is configured to use the On-premises XML process model, you can **only** use that process model to customize the work tracking experience. If you want to add a work item type and add a new state, please customize via the XML.

If you want to customize your process from the UI, it's suggested that you create a collection using the inheritance process model.